# Java: getting info from a specific line in files

Tags: java, file, authentication

I have made this nice login program with all usernames in one .txt file and all passwords in the other. so when the user enters a username and it corresponds to one of the names on for example line 5 of the first file, I want the program to read the password from the 5th line in the second file and see if it matches with the password given by the user. I just don't know how to read from a specific file or how to see on what line it is,

here is the code I have now.

```
package databarry_;


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class interfacelogin {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    boolean check1=false, check2=false, check3=false;
    int trys = 3;
    while (check3 == false){

        int id1 = 0;
        int id2 = 0;

        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        Scanner fileout = null;
        Scanner fileout2 = null;


        try{
            fileout = new Scanner(new File("username.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fatal Error, please Reboot or reinstal program", "Boot", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        String Username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your username");
        while(fileout.hasNext()){
            username = fileout.next();
            if(Username.equals(username))
                check1=true;
        }
        try{
            fileout2 = new Scanner(new File("password.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fatal Error, please Reboot or reinstal program", "Boot", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        String Password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your username");
        while(fileout2.hasNext()){
            password = fileout2.next();
            if(Password.equals(password) && id1 == id2)
                check2=true;
        }

        if (check1 == true && check2 == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "succeded", "login", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            check3 = true;
        } else {
            if (trys > 1){
            trys--;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "bad login, you have " + trys + " try's remaining", "login", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);        
            } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "To many bad logins, program is closing", "login", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    check3 = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

as you can see the only big flow is that if you enter a password and username that ar not on the same line (so not linked to each other) in the files (like both on line 5) the user gets trough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do so is to read both files and store your login/password pairs in a

```
HashMap<String, String>
```

Then you can easily check, if entered login-password pair is a match.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

while(fileout.hasNext() && fileout2.hasNext()){
    username = fileout.next();
    password = fileout2.next();
    map.put(username, password);
}

...

if (password.equals(map.get(username)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you but why does it take the username and compares to the password:

if (password.equals(map.get(username))){

Comment: See. A map has keys (usernames) and values(passwords), and each KEY is assigned a VALUE. When you do .get operation, it finds a VALUE using a KEY. E.g. map:(denis->123, codemaster->000). Then map.get("denis") is 123. What you then do is compare a password, entered by user, to its actual password, read from file.

Comment: thank you but i can't get it to work in the program because i am new to java. (before c/c++

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have problems with memory, or if the amount of users is not so high, I suggest you to read together both files only once when the program starts, and store the data in a HashMap using the user as key and the password as value:

```
BufferedReader users = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("username.txt"));
BufferedReader passwords = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("password.txt"));
HashMap logins = new HashMap<String, String>();        
String user,pass;
while ((user=users.readLine())!=null) {
    pass=passwords.readLine();
    logins.put(user, pass);
}
```

and then to check a username/password:

```
String username = null; //the username specified by the user
String password = null; //the password specified by the user
if (logins.get(user).compareTo(password)==0) {
    //correct pass
} else {
    //wrong pass
}
```

This is only a sketch to give you and idea (it does not consider special cases, as the user insert a username that does not exists, and so on...)